# Changing the cache settings of the page

Tags: html, mozilla, html5-audio

I want to disable browser caching for my site. How do I do that? I load an audio file according to the image in my page, image gets refreshed all the time but audio remains the same only in Mozilla, whereas it is working fine for Chrome. So I want to disable the caching process. So that Mozilla doesn't load the audio file from the cache.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend doing this through your .htaccess file. All of the following code is taken from [html5 boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate). Basically this is a cache control list that contains every type of web resource you can think of. So if you want your audio to have no cache just set the the appropriate line in the snippet to the value "access plus 0 seconds".

Hope this works for you.

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Expires headers (for better cache control)
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# These are pretty far-future expires headers.
# They assume you control versioning with filename-based cache busting
# Additionally, consider that outdated proxies may miscache
#   www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/

# If you don't use filenames to version, lower the CSS and JS to something like
# "access plus 1 week".

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on

# Perhaps better to whitelist expires rules? Perhaps.
  ExpiresDefault                          "access plus 1 month"

# cache.appcache needs re-requests in FF 3.6 (thanks Remy ~Introducing HTML5)
  ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest       "access plus 0 seconds"

# Your document html
  ExpiresByType text/html                 "access plus 0 seconds"

# Data
  ExpiresByType application/json          "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xml           "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/xml                  "access plus 0 seconds"

# Feed
  ExpiresByType application/atom+xml      "access plus 1 hour"
  ExpiresByType application/rss+xml       "access plus 1 hour"

# Favicon (cannot be renamed)
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon              "access plus 1 week"

# Media: images, video, audio
  ExpiresByType audio/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/gif                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg                "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/png                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/webm                "access plus 1 month"

# HTC files  (css3pie)
  ExpiresByType text/x-component          "access plus 1 month"

# Webfonts
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf    "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff   "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType font/opentype             "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml             "access plus 1 month"

# CSS and JavaScript
  ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType text/css                  "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>
```

Comment: I did not understand this at all.. :-0 But I'll give it a try. And where do I find this file. And where do I place it in my project. I use Glassfish server.